# GLSL 4.3 - Assign Array

Tags: c++, arrays, glsl

I need to copy the data from an array of 32 `uint`s into another array of 32 `uint`s.

Is there any special technique to do this? Right now I just use:

```
for(uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
   array1[i] = array2[i];
}
```

The arrays are exactly the same. Same type, same size. Like, some sort of standard `memcpy` for GLSL?

Comment: Not sure about this (never had the need for it), but it is very likely that you can just do: `uint array1[32] = { uint[32](array2) };`.

Comment: Huh. The use I have was making a temporary buffer for a conway's game of life block. Though now, I don't need to do this anymore :P. But I do need to fill an array with zeroes. I will check your technique, so thank you!

Comment: @glampert Well, turns out I'm an idiot. You can just assign it directly. `array1 = array2`. Wow, I thought I tried that, and here I was searching "copy array glsl" in google 30 different ways. Well, at least I found it out. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know, @BWG. Might need it sometime ;)